# IBM 53 qubit cloud access

Tags: ibm-q-experience

IBM announced a 53 qubit chip.

Will the advertised chip be available for non-paying users, or only to IBM clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 53 qubit Rochester machine is available to members of the IBM Q Network only.  Currently there are eight systems available to the public via the IBM Quantum Experience and by extension the Qiskit framework.  The largest of these systems is currently 15 qubits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if official information has been released yet, though it will likely have a mix of research and industry applications, considering IBM's previous policies ([research](https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/network/researchers), [industry](https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/network/overview))

Answer (score 0):

An open question is whether IBM has created a single 53-qubit chip, or if they are mass-producing the 53-qubit chip. Based on press accounts, it appears that there is only a single chip, and that is a research machine.

[MIT Technology Review](https://www.technologyreview.com/f/614346/ibms-new-53-qubit-quantum-computer-is-the-most-powerful-machine-you-can-use/) reports that the new computer will be made available for researchers and companies through the Internet (which TR annoyingly calls "the cloud"), so my guess is that there is only a single machine.